# Is wrapping built-in functions with user functions ok?

Tags: php, naming

As I was working with a friend on a project I noticed that he created custom functions such as:

```
function is_empty($val){
  return empty($val);
}
function is_not_empty($val){
  return !empty($val);
}
function is_set($val){
  return isset($val);
}
function is_not_set($val){
  return !isset($val);
}
```

and is using them instead of the built in functions. I tried talking him out of this practice but he insists that this "naming convention" is to make the code more "understandable".

I would like to know your opinions about the issue, and is this regular behavior or not?

Comment: I think you can get your answer [from the Clever Coder](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Clever-Coder) ;).

Comment: Assuming this is PHP, you should add that to the question's tags for clarity.

Answer (score 7):

**It depends**.

When designing programs, the most important reason for creating functions is IMHO to create useful abstractions. For example, sometimes a program designer wants to abstract from a specific API or a certain framework, and creates an intermediate layer, so a user of that API depends only on that layer, but not on the underlying API itself. Or, one wants to create a create a specific datatype  based on a built-in datatype type of the underlying API, and provides a complete set of functions for accessing this abstract datatype.

For these cases, it can be perfectly fine to wrap single built-in functions, to create a complete and coherent set of own functions encapsulating something.

However, there are also wrong reasons for doing this. For example, when the newly created functions don't provide any real abstraction from the underlying framework, or when the abstraction is not really needed and does not provide any benefit (which occurs often when someone created it "just in case").

For example, in the case shown in your question, it is debatable if the new functions provide clearer names for someone who is familiar with the underlying framework or programming language. If those functions now lead to code which uses built-in functions directly, intermixed with these "newly invented" functions, then it does probably not make the code clearer, quite the opposite.

If you have an accepted naming convention in your team how to name certain functions, and the whole team follows that convention rigidly, then it can indeed make sense to encapsulate built-in functions in the shown way because of the names will fit better to the team's naming conventions. However, I guess your team does not have such a convention, otherwise you would not have asked the question here in the first place.

Comment: This is PHP and next to nothing to do with mathematical sets.

Comment: @user949300: thanks, edited answer accordingly

Answer (score 5):

No this is not regular behavior. This is likely to lead to confusion when developers who were unfamiliar with the original framework go to work on a new project that uses the same framework but doesn't have the wrappers. Developers who know the framework will call it directly, and this will lead to bifurcation of the code where some developers call the wrappers and others don't. It also likely degrades performance as a single function call now becomes 2 function calls - the first to the wrapper and the second from the wrapper to the original function.

Comment: Best answer, upvoted, but minor quibble: the performance hit is trivial and irrelevant to this discussion.  Confusion and bifurcation are the real points.

Comment: My point exactly. I won't lay to you, I have done it once before in the name of "naming convention" and ended up calling the original function directly. The performance is an extra cost.

Comment: In PHP in some cases the performance can be measurable, but still wouldnt consider that really relevant. Good abstractions are normally worth it even when they nearly always have a performance cost. But "renaming" functions/constructs from the langauge itself? Thats just a source of confusion, inconsistency and arguments.

Answer (score 5):

For these specific operations it's no good idea. `empty` and `isset` are no functions, but language constructs.

Passing undefined things to these won't produce an error and not create those elements. Calling the wrapping functions will however.

The only reason for wrapping `empty` would be to be able to call it indirectly like this:

```
<?php
function is_empty($var) {
    return empty($var);
}
$is_empty = "is_empty";
$is_empty($foo[42]); // will produce error and create $foo in scope

array_filter($array, "is_empty"); // might be more useful than example above

array_filter($array, function ($e) { return empty $e; }); // might be the nicer, more explicit, form in modern PHP, though
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely okay, depending on circumstances. For example, way back when, I was working on a VAX/VMS/C project that I knew would be ported to Unix several years down the road. VMS had lots of unusual-but-useful stuff like logical name services. I wrapped all those kinds of built-in functions (what they call system services) as user functions, knowing they could be rewritten when the time came. In particular, I had one module where a whole mess of such functions were wrapped, and where all the VMS-specific #include's appeared. So just that one module was affected by the eventual port.

Otherwise, there'd have been VMS-specific stuff all over the place. For example, many of these VMS-specific calls take what they call "string descriptors" as arguments, rather than the usual C null-terminated strings. My wrappers took usual strings as arguments, and did all the housekeeping to re-cast them as descriptors in that one place. Without that, each module would need to #include descrip (a VMS-ism for #include <descrip.h>) and would have to declare some strange-looking "descriptors". Then the port would've required extensive editing -- not a whole lot of thinking, but tons of editing.

You can take a look at a module containing many of those wrapper functions at http://www.forkosh.com/listings/vmslib.c.html (the VMS logical name services were collected in a separate module)

Comment: I think VMS/UNIX compatibility abstractions are a very different thing from "I dont like the **languages** own naming convention, so instead of `isset` (which is always there and every PHP dev should know) we will call it `is_set` (now where is that defined? Does every project have it?)". Unless you would also have abstracted the entire C standard library iteself so you could have `stringLength` instead of `strlen` etc. because your *team* liked lower camal case or maybe `StringLength` to align more with Win32?

Answer (score -1):

It depends, but IMO,
I prefer to wrap-and-add-more-feature, and avoid [disaster like this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50696).

Also for consistency and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

example:

```
<?php
// wrap date() to display my-country-common-date-format
function fn_date_format($custom_date = null) {
  $format = 'd F Y';
  if(empty($custom_date)) return date($format);
  return date($format, strtotime($custom_date));
}

// result:
echo fn_date_format(); // 28 September 2017 (today)
echo fn_date_format('2000-05-22'); // 22 May 2000
```

*(sory for my english)*

Comment: why -1 without any explaination